# Adding expand/collapse feature to Discovery sidebar in DSpace 4.2 xmlui

Tags: javascript, jquery, dspace

I've started using DSpace recently and I'm trying to add expand/collapse feature to the Discovery sidebar in DSpace 4.2 xmlui using Mirage theme. I found some `jquery` code which will help me do so.

I tried to do so by placing the `js` file in `/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.17/webapps/xmlui/static/js/discovery` and referencing it from the Discovery `sitemap.xmap` file (`/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.17/webapps/xmlui/WEB-INF/classes/aspects/Discovery/sitemap.xmap`).

```
  <map:transform type="SidebarFacetsTransformer">
        <map:parameter name="javascript.static#1" value="loadJQuery.js"/>
        <map:parameter name="javascript.static#2" value="static/js/discovery/jquery.collapsible.js"/>
    </map:transform>
```

But it's not working.
Could someone please point out where I need to place the code, and which files I need to modify.

Thanks in advance

This shows the home page. As you can see the debugger is showing the file `jquery-collapsible.js` which is the custom file which I've added to DSpace. The expand/collapse is working on this page.

[image]

This is the discovery page in which the debugger is not showing my file, and the expand/collapse is also not working.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try referencing your `js` file in `[dspace]\webapps\xmlui\themes\Mirage\sitemap.xmap` inside the `<map:transform type="IncludePageMeta">`. The default value looked like [this:](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-4.2/dspace-xmlui/src/main/webapp/themes/Mirage/sitemap.xmap#L140-L145)

```
        <map:transform type="IncludePageMeta">
            <map:parameter name="stylesheet.all" value="lib/css/media.css"/>
            <map:parameter name="javascript" value="lib/js/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.min.js"/>
            <map:parameter name="theme.path" value="{global:theme-path}"/>
            <map:parameter name="theme.name" value="{global:theme-path}"/>
        </map:transform>
```

Change

`<map:parameter name="javascript" value="lib/js/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.min.js"/>`

to

`<map:parameter name="javascript#1" value="lib/js/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.min.js"/>`

and then add

`<map:parameter name="javascript#2" value="lib/js/your-custom-js#1.js"/>`
`<map:parameter name="javascript#3" value="lib/js/your-custom-js#2.js"/>`
and so on and so forth. The `lib/js` directory by the way is located inside the Mirage theme folder.

I would also suggest that you use firefox's firebug plugin to check for (javascript) errors or google chrome's inpector because you might encounter jquery conflict along the way.

Hope this help.

Comment: thanks it did help. Now my jquery is loading on the homepage, but not on subsequent pages ( I figured it out from the firefox debugger ). Maybe there are some other files in which I need to add references?

Comment: Did you encounter any errors in your firefox debugger?

Comment: Maybe this [thread](http://dspace.2283337.n4.nabble.com/Accordion-menu-for-Discovery-tt4663393.html) can help you.

Comment: I've edited my question to include screenshots of the debugger. Please have a look if you can make out anything. I'll go through the link you shared.

Comment: Ok so I added my jquery code to the `discovery-results.js` file within `[dspace]/webapps/xmlui/static/js/Discovery` and that seems to solve my problem.

Comment: Glad it solved your problem. You have to be extra careful that any script you write only targets the DOM elements you intend to target, and nothing else (meaning, target DOM elements using their IDs and/or very specific class names). Please also note that the ordering or sequence of files that you are referencing is crucial (ie if your script requires jquery, it should not be placed before the jquery file) in your sitemap.xmap.